# Is this a coin, token or medallion?

Tags: naval, australia

I found this attached to a rock, on a beach in Western Australia a number of years ago.
I cannot identify the Coat of Arms although have looked in numerous sites.
The reverse appears to be a Lion Rampant. Could be silver but highly corroded.[image]

Comment: How large (or small) is this?

Comment: Have you checked the coats of arms of all European colonial powers (it doesn't look like any of them to me) and the major trading companies, and the coats of arms of Australia, the Australian states, and Australian communities?  A lion rampant could be from the arms of Scotland, Spain (Leon), Norway, Sweden, or Austria (Bohemia).   It looks like there is horizontal lines in the coat of arms, which became the usual hatching for blue by about 1700, and drops or ermine tails, with a bend sinister, and something in the other part of the shield.

Comment: It’s possible this is some sort of seal, in which case you would be looking for this image -reversed-. @MAGolding

Comment: I had not considered this to be a seal due to being two sided but will do some checking.

Comment: The 'Object' measures 30mm but is badly corroded on the outer rim so I believe it was about 33 to 34mm originally. There are a few letter around the outside but cannot make them out. I have previously checked the Colonial Powers and agree I cannot find a match.Also cannot find an exact match to countries mentioned by MAGolding although Scotland is closest.

Comment: I think we can dismiss the idea of a Seal as the lettering would come out in revers in the wax.

Comment: The lion rampart could also be from a Dutch seal, but I don't recognise it. Might be a family seal from some large trading family. The lower part of the shield might indicate water, which would be in line with a sea faring family or city.

Comment: Thanks for all the help so far. After more accurate measurement I believe the original diameter to be 40mm. The Idea of it being Dutch origin is probably near the mark. It is possibly a Lion Silver Daalder Dollar from mid 1600's. The Dutch were in WA prior to the British. I will keep digging.